# loop to select first and last values in 2 columns in R

Tags: r, loops

I need to loop into df2 and take the first value in df2$col1 and the last value in df2$col2 and use those values to only select the corresponding rows and all in between in df1$col1

If you can help me with this I'd really appreciate it!

df1

```
col1 
1 
2
3
4
5
etc
```

df2

```
col1 col2
1200  1250
1299  1325 
1350  1500
```

Comment: `\`[\`` subsetting will be useful to you. I recommend typing `?"["` in the console.

Comment: And also `help("[.data.frame")`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by SimonO101, you can use `"["` and `%in%`.

Try this:

```
df1[df1$col1 %in% head(df2,1)[1,1] : tail(df2, 1)[1,2], , drop=FALSE]
```

### Edit

As @flodel commented you can even use `<=` to be more efficient

```
df1[df2[1,1] <= df1$col1 & df1$col1 <= df2[nrow(df2),2], , drop=FALSE]
```

equivalent to

```
df1[df1$col1 >= df2[1,1] & df1$col1 <= df2[nrow(df2),2], , drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: the OP has two data.frames `df1` and `df2`, in your solution there's only one, does it answer the question? Am I missing something? :O

Comment: No it is I who was missing the second data.frame name! I thought there was only one.

Comment: Using `>=` and `<=` should be a lot more efficient.